# Partial View Not Working?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry if my question is newbie. I'm quite new to MVC 4.

I want to show the Question List View which have the data list (with Edit, Details, Delete) inside another View. Is it possible?

**_QuestionList.cshtml Code:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<Example.Models.SurveyQuestionModel>

    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Question)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Answer)</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Answer)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit.cshtml Code:**

```
@model Example.Models.SurveyModel

@Html.Partial("_QuestionList")
```

Is anything that i missed out?

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to define 2 models.

Comment: Exactly, it only allow 1 model in each view. Any alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using HTML.Action instead of Partial & modify at SurveyController:

```
 public ActionResult _QuestionList()
        {

            return PartialView(db.SurveyQuestionModels.ToList());
        }
```

Edit.cshtml Code:

```
 @Html.Action("_QuestionList", "Survey")
```

Thanks for yours help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks almost right, but you need to pass the model to the partial view, so

```
@Html.Partial("_QuestionList", Model.SurveyQuestions)
```

Assuming your `Example.Models.SurveyModel` has a property of `SurveyQuestions` which is an `IEnumerable<Example.Models.SurveyQuestionModel>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May i know how to add the property ? Appreciate it.

Comment: @Edward.K, `public IEnumerable<Example.Models.SurveyQuestionModel> SurveyQuestions {get;set;}` then you need to populate `SurveyQuestions` when you populate the rest of the properties.